# jquery mobile multipage with javascript template, does not always "refresh"

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I have a multi-page jQuery mobile page.

When I go from Page 1 to Page 2 I see my template that I dynamically create using handlebars.

The template:

```
<script id="history-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="share_history" >
       <h3>{{share_title}}</h3>
       {{#each historyItem}}
          <h2>Shared with {{shared_with}}</h2>
          {{#list people}}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}, {{role}}{{/list}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

The javascript:

```
var context = {
    share_title: "View Share History",
    historyItem:  [
            {
                shared_with: "with a group",
                people: [
                    {firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Wong", role: "Dad" },
                    {firstName: "Tina", lastName: "Turner", role: "Guardian" },
                    {firstName: "Modest", lastName: "Mouse", role: "Dad" }
                ]
            },
            {
                shared_with: "with 3 people",
                people: [
                    {firstName: "Baily", lastName: "Wong", role: "Dad" },
                    {firstName: "Gina", lastName: "Turner", role: "Guardian" },
                    {firstName: "Modest", lastName: "Mouse", role: "Dad" }
                ]
            }
        ]

};

var source   = $("#history-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(people, options) {
var out = "<ul class=>";

for(var i=0, l=people.length; i<l; i++) {
out = out + "<li>" + options.fn(people[i]) + "</li>";
}

return out + "</ul>";
});

    var html    = template(context);

    $('#share').html(html);
$.mobile.changePage('#add-edit');
```

When I go from Page 1 to Page 2 (in my multipage layout) it works (good).

**But** if I click the back button, and **then** go back to Page 2, I see my content...minus the additional markup jQuery mobile adds (i.e. I see content but not my jQuery mobile appearance/theme).

**Edit**

For my example, I had to do the following:

```
$('#share').html(html).trigger( "create" );
```

Comment: You need to [trigger](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) a `create` on your page to tell JQM to initialize your widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to trigger the create event on the html element, e.g

```
el.trigger('create');
```

Comment: @redconservatory I battled the same issue last week :)